# How to add launch image to a Sencha Touch 2 app?

Tags: ios, extjs, sencha-touch-2

The iOS guideline requires launch image for all apps. To my understanding, that's a "default.png" file located in the root folder of your app.
I packaged my app using Sencha CMD v3 and I don't see any launch image while loading.
There are some default launch images located in root/webapp/resources/loading/ folder but they are not showed in my app. Any idea?

The ["startupImage"](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-startupImage) seems only appliable to the app added to the home screen, anyway, here is a part of my app.js:

```
startupImage: {
    '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
    '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
    '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
    '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
    '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
    '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
}
```

Added related posts:

- [[2.1] Splash screen is white on startup on Android and iOS](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?252028-2.1-Splash-screen-is-white-on-startup-on-Android-and-iOS)

Comment: this startup image is ony when it is hosted as a website, i you want to add startup image on android then you have to use splash screen for android.

Comment: I've been using 'phoneStartupScreen' and 'tabletStartupScreen' properties, they definitely work. I need to figure out an alternative though as this doesn't help for iphone 5...

Answer (score 1):

I have this at the beginning of my application - I'm not packaging it for iOS, but this seems like what you may need:

```
Ext.require([    
    'Ext.XTemplate',
    'Ext.Panel',
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.List'
]);

// Main application entry point
Ext.application({
    phoneStartupScreen: 'images/sencha_logo.png',
    name: 'Analytics',

// setup our MVC items
```

Here is a handy-dandy link to the api doc on this:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-phoneStartupScreen

Answer (score 1):

For launch image you need to modify the **index.html** in your app directory. In here you will find a div with id **appLoadingIndicator** inside **body** tag. In my application I have replaced the content of  #appLoadingIndicator with an img tag which refers to my splash image.

```
<div id="appLoadingIndicator">
  <img src="resources/images/splash.png" /> 
</div>
```

For customizing the css you might want to remove the default embedded styles in **index.html** present in style tag inside the head tag which are applied to **#appLoadingIndicator**.

Now add your custom css and you will have your splash image ready.

Comment: After testing I found out that splash screen was not visible in android phone. So added phoneStartupScreen: variable in app.js and it worked fine. Follow the url: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-phoneStartupScreen for more details.